# Moving a div from inside one div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I move the contents of a div to the contents of another div?

I want to move .sidebar from .post to .carousel. How to do it by using javascript?

I want to go from this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="post">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
      </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="post"></div>
      <div class="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mind using jQuery?

Comment: @laaposto I do not mind to use jQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, on the off-chance you've more than one element with that class (and assuming that in all instances they should be inserted after their `parentNode`):

```
$('.sidebar').each(function(){
    $(this).insertAfter(this.parentNode);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ug9Br/1/).

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).

Comment: .insertAfter(this.parentNode) is the answer I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0].appendChild(document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0]);
```

Comment: Second line is unnecessary: no need to empty `.post` when the third line moves `.sidebar`. Upvote for vanilla JS though, as I was just about to post =)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have only one such occurrence, you can use plain JavaScript:

```
var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0];

// move after parent node
sidebar.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(sidebar);
```

The `appendChild()` function moves rather than copies existing elements from their previous location in the tree. To perform a copy you would need to clone the respective elements first.

Comment: This will give the added convenience over simple vanilla JS - posted by Dude - of moving all elements with a class of `sidebar`.

Comment: @HenryBlyth The question is tagged with jquery, so you might as well use it :)

Comment: @HenryBlyth Turns out I didn't read the question properly; the node be should moved after its parent node, not become a child of carousel :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JQuery **Draggable() and Droppable()** functions.
See the Demo...

[Droppable | JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)